# Building Visual Studio projects for 2 Frameworks Simultaneously

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build-automation

I have a few class libraries that I'm using in two of our in-house projects. One of the in-house projects targets the *.NET 4.0 framework*, while the other one targets *.NET 2.0*. I'm using [LinqBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) to gain some of the niceties of the higher version .NETs in the 2.0 project.

In order to use the class libraries properly in both projects, I need to compile one version (using LinqBridge) to the .NET 2.0 Framework, and another version (using the standard System.Linq) for .NET 4.0.

I'd like to avoid doing this manually every time. I was hoping there was a way to specify what the current target framework is in the Build Events section, but it looks like there isn't a macro for that. I'm generally unfamiliar with manually editing build configurations. **What's the right way to go about targeting two frameworks for a single project?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would simply create two separate projects in a single solution, one for the 2.0 and one for the 4.0 targets. They could reference the same source files and the 2.0 could add the extra references needed.

That would allow you to build the solution and get both the 2.0 and 4.0 target DLLs to include in whatever other projects you need.

Comment: Makes sense. I wasn't aware you could share source across multiple solutions.

Comment: This is a good idea, but it's worth pointing out that you really want to keep the two project files in the same directory, because otherwise you'll need to use linked files, which will quickly become painful.

Comment: Separate directories and linked files are not so bad, especially once you run into things that you may need to maintain two source code versions for. Too much `#if #endif` does become painful. If you choose to use the same directory, make sure your output paths are different.

Comment: @Roger For the record, I am going to be doing it in the same directory for now. The changes are simple enough so I shouldn't need to rely on preprocessor statements. Thanks for the suggestion. +1